Proving $\nu = f\mu$ with $0 \leq f \leq 1$ when $\nu ≤ \mu$ in a σ-finite measure space
Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $\nu$ be another measure on $(S, \Sigma)$. Show that if $\nu(A) \leq \mu(A)$, for all $A \in \Sigma$, then $\nu = f \mu$ for some (a.e. uniquely determined) density function $f$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$.
Attempt: Let $A \in \Sigma$. Since $\nu \ll \mu$, by Radon-Nikodym theorem, we have that $\nu(A) = \int_{A}f d\mu = (f \mu)(A)$ for some nonnegative $\mu$-integrable and $\Sigma/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable $f$. Hence, we only need to show that $0 \leq f \leq 1$.
Question: How do I continue from this point onwards?

I don't think you have understood  the correct meaning of $\nu=f\mu$.

$\nu=f\mu$ means $\nu (A)=\int_A fd\mu$ for any $A \in \Sigma$.

I fixed my question. Thanks!

$\frac  1 {\mu(A)}\int_A fd\mu \in [0,1]$ for every set $A$ of positive measure  implies $0 \le f \le 1$ a.e. Ref.: Rudin's RCA

I do not really understand why $(f \mu)(A) =\frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A f d\mu$.

Theres no equality -- use the fact that $\nu(A) \leq \mu(A)$ and $f \mu = \nu$ to get that $\frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_A f d\mu \in [0,1]$ for every set $A$ with positive measure.

If $f>1$ on $A$ having $\mu(A)>0$ then $\nu(A)=(f\mu)(A)>\mu(A).$
